# how to start a video from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, video

The terminal is where everything gets done in linux.

So if this is true, how can I play an AVI video (`.avi` extension) from the Terminal?

Answer (score 48):

The syntax to open any file in its default application is

```
xdg-open <file_name>
```

If you want to have some fun and play the video in the terminal itself, install mplayer (`sudo apt-get install mplayer`) and run

```
mplayer -vo caca <movie_file>
```

It doesn't run directly in the terminal window, but it does display in ASCII characters.

Comment: xdg-open name.mov worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04 from Terminal connected using SSH. The other one showed things very weirdly. Thanks

Comment: @MonaJalal haha the second one was just a fun command that tries to display the movie as ascii characters within the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

In general you start any command from a terminal by entering the command.

So to edit a file with gedit

```
gedit file_to_edit
```

An .avi is no different, just a different command

```
banshee your.avi
```

You may use any media player you wish.

the only thing is an avi itself is a container, so you may need to install some codecs. codecs are the tools to play mp3 and other audio visual files.

this link may help

[LinuxCommand](http://linuxcommand.org/)

Comment: general syntax is `<program> <file to be played>`

Answer (score 2):

`totem` can be anoter option. On my fresh installed `Xenial` it's the app that opens movie files from nautilus.
It's [available from Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=totem).

Comment: In addition to this, totem is the default video player for Gnome, and if you want to play video that requires authentication, like for example a password-protected video, typing `totem 'url'`, will launch the player and ask you for a username/password

Answer (score 0):

Even arguments can be used, in terminal:

```
videoplayer-name videoplayer-arguments path-to-file
```

Path to file can be easily entered by dragging and dropping the file onto the terminal window.

Example, to only listen to the music of a video concert:

```
mpv --no-video file-dropped-onto-terminal-window
```